# Independent classes

Tags: c#, methods, dependencies, partial

I was wondering if there is to have two partial classes, with the same methods, to both do some work, but not being dependent of each other.

For instance, I want to be able to have a parent class calling a function "DoFoo()". The first class would return "1234", the second return "5678", so it would return "12345678". When I remove the second class (that returned "5678"), it would only return "1234". The only way I could think of to implement this, is by firing an event, and having the second and first class subscribe to that event, and when I remove the second class, it would not effect the parent class at all (dependency injection).

Any ideas?

Comment: your data example sounds like the [decorator pattern](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-query-syntax) would work for you. Have you ever heard of it? Here is [another example](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/479635/UnderstandingplusandplusImplementingplusDecoratorp)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

Comment: Glad to hear, have fun decorating ;)